# MySQL - Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

So i have the query below which runs perfectly, but I get the error in the title and I don't understand why. Maybe someone can help.

Query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO paypal_log (product_name) VALUES ('".$_POST["product_name"]."')");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $product_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Error:

> PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/triponsergiu/public_html/test/includes/paypal.php on line 29

Thank you.

Comment: You don't use your `s`(placeholder) in the prepared statement! Also you messed something with the quotes up

Comment: You're not setting any placeholders in your sql statement, but interpolating a value directly :( Use a `?` placeholder instead, then you can bind your value to that placeholder

Comment: why are you binding parameter, despite you added direct value to product_name field in prepare statement, comment this line "$stmt->bind_param('s', $product_name);" and give it a try...

Comment: @ZAZ - better fix is to use the bind var and not to use the interpolated product name, especially as it isn't even escaped

Comment: Read the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Mark Baker, yes, you are right, i agree with you, actually he used direct value in his prepare statement thts y i suggested this. however, he has both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding parameters to statements means filling in a parameter in the statement that was left 'blank'. To create a 'blank', replace a value with, for example, a question mark.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO paypal_log (product_name) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $product_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This way, the parameter is automatically escaped (so they can't delete or download your entire database...).

Comment: If I don't want to create a blank, and instead get the value from the POST, would `$product_name = '".$_POST["product_name"]."';` and then just using the variable on the bind_param and the question mark in the statement, work?

Comment: You can replace `$product_name` with `$POST['product_name']` in my code example. However, be careful! Check that the product name you get in the POST is something sensible (does it even exist?) and not too long (I can POST a fake product name of 1 000 000 characters long, for example)...

Comment: In my case, the product name is fixed and cannot be edited by the user, as the field is readonly.

Comment: @SergiuTripon: A smart user can change the field to whatever he wants (right click => inspect element). A malicious user can send POST requests to your site without even using a browser. Sanitize your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO paypal_log (product_name) VALUES (?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST["product_name"]);
```

- [**Consult the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) on prepared statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was me. "Try this" as sole answer context is overly unhelpful to obvious newcomer questions / future visitors.

Comment: @mario The answerer had a link to prepared statements manual, which I rectified. It was worded wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wasn't watching the sneak edits. But an RTFM link is indeed slightly better.

Comment: @mario True indeed. A comment which I made under OP's question to that effect also, to RTFM ;)